# PL and triangulizable

Tags: geometric-topology

Is it correct that the notion of triangulizable manifold (in the sence "homeomorphic to a simplicial complex") is weaker than the notion of a PL-manifold?
If yes, why? (eg is it true that a star of vertex in a general triangulizable manifold need not be a ball contrary to the PL case?) And are there sufficient and necessary condition on manifold for two notions being equivalent.